# Deleting blog post using Blogger API, Javascript and Prototype

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, blogger

I'm trying to delete a blog post on blogger.com using Blogger API via Prototype Javascript library. Here's my code:

```
var request = new Ajax.Request(
    'http://www.blogger.com/feeds/'+remoteBlogId+'/posts/default/'+postId
    {
        method:'DELETE',
        requestHeaders:['Authorization', 'GoogleLogin auth='+authKey],
        on200:function(){/*onSuccess*/},
        onFailure:function(){/*onFailure*/}
    }
);
```

As far as I can see from API description, everything's alright, but when I run this, it fires onSuccess function, but doesn't delete the entry on the server.

I guess that  Prototype doesn't work well with HTTP methods other than GET and POST ([here's the ticket](https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/289/) describing similar problem though proposed patch didn't work for me)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: UPD: I really don't need cross-browser availability, I need only support for webkit-based browser. Does anyone know something about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery - [here's an article](http://homework.nwsnet.de/news/9132_put-and-delete-with-jquery) that shows how to use REST methods in jQuery Ajax. jQuery is much more known framework than Prototype.

Comment: If DELETE is not supported by the browser, switching to jQuery will not help.

Comment: Solution found - jQuery handles DELETE and PUT methods properly

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers support PUT and DELETE - this is regardless of what JS library you're using.  See this topic:
[Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)